# Powershell & Windows 8 - Permission denied obtaining content of link in recent items folder

Tags: powershell, permissions

In Windows 8.1, I am trying to tidy the recent items folder on login with a powershell script called from a cmd batch file. The .BAT successfully deletes all .LNK files with mp3 etc in their name (leaving text files, Word files and other links I want to keep) the .PS1 script is for deleting all links to folders. When it gets to executing

> $FilePath = Get-Content $file.FullName
>   it fails with a permission denied error (UnauthorizedAccessException). So I suppose I also don't have permission to execute CreateShortcut either. I can copy files into the recent items folder in a .BAT. UAC is enabled, I am running the script in PowerShell ISE as an administrator.

This is the script:-

```
Set-StrictMode -version 2  
$VerbosePreference = "Continue"  
$sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell  

$files = Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent"   

foreach ($file in $files)   
{  
   $FilePath = Get-Content $file.FullName  
   $TargetPath = $sh.CreateShortcut($FilePath).TargetPath  
   if (test-path $TargetPath -PathType Container)  
   {  
       remove-item ($FilePath) -Force  
   }  
}
```

Comment: Do you have some anti-virus software that might be getting in the way? I've seen this cause access denied messages before.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late to the party, but I came across this issue:
The issue was to do with:

```
Set-StrictMode -version 2
```

I took it out for my purposes, and resolved this issue.